# book chapters on either Ramanujan or Chebychev proof of Bertrand postulate

Tags: number-theory

I'm looking for book chapters on either Ramanujan or Chebychev proof of Bertrand postulate but not Erdos (no disrespect to him).
I've come across:

Harold N. Shapiro Introduction to the Theory of Numbers

Chapter 9 covers Ramanujan, Chebychev and Erdo's approach.

but I would  like some other explanations from other books to help me understand so that I do not have to come back here to ask thing I have not grasped.

Any reference suggestions would be welcome.

Thanks in advance.

P.S I'm particularly interested in a detailed proof of how the limits for the Chebychev function is found used for Bertrand postulate without resorting to the Binomial coefficients.

Comment: Try Daniel I A Cohen, Basic Techniques of Combinatorial Theory.

Comment: @Gerry Myerson I looked at that book - a very good book -  but I could not see Chebychev or Ramanujan approach to this problem. A detailed proof of how the limits for the Chebychev function used for Bertrand postulate without resorting to the Binomial theorem would be good.

Comment: "without resorting to the Binomial theorem" Do you mean, without using binomial coefficients? The proofs I know use binomial coefficients, but they don't use the Binomial Theorem.

Comment: @Gerry Myerson thanks for pointing that oversight  out - yes binomial coefficients.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Shapiro chapter looks very good to me, but if you want a couple of other sources, you could look at Tenenbaum and Mendes France, The Prime Numbers and Their Distribution, pages 16 to 20, and also Niven, Zuckerman, and Montgomery, An Introduction to the Theory of Numbers, Fifth Edition, pages 360 to 368.

The first book says, "We shall exploit Chebyshev's original idea, but in a rudimentary form." This gets them $${c_1x\over\log x}\le\pi(x)\le{c_2x\over\log x}$$ with $c_1=\log2+o(1)$, $c_2=2\log2+o(1)$, which is not quite good enough to get Bertrand. Then they hint at how Chebyshev got the estimate with better values of $c_1$ and $c_2$, good enough to get Bertrand for all large $n$, and then they write, "By making explicit an effective version of his estimates, Chebyshev was able to prove that [a certain inequality] remains true for all $n>3$," which confirms Bertrand.

The other book says, "We follow [Chebyshev's] method quite closely." I think all the details are there.

Neither book mentions Ramanujan in the context of Bertrand.

Comment: Had a chance to look at these, onepound?

Comment: thanks, just reviewing them now! yes I'm liking both references and especially the detail of Niven, Zuckerman, and Montgomery's book which I think will help me understand Chebyshev's method more fully.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one--Chapter 24, pp.208-09, *Collected Papers ~ Ramanujan* (AMS Chelsea, 1962): A Proof of Bertrand's Postulate.

Comment: There is also a proof in vol. I of Landau's 2-volume work on number theory, which is available for free online.

Comment: thanks for the references. Is that to be found in the English translation Elementary Number Theory by Edmund Landau?

Comment: @onepound: i think that's different. this one is two volumes and as far as i know there's no english translation. first word in title is "handbuch" but it wouldn't fit in anyone's hand.

Comment: thanks I've found the German version: https://archive.org/stream/handbuchderlehre01landuoft#page/90/mode/2up/search/bertrand  see how I go.