# what sort of proof did Chebyshev use to prove Bertrand's conjecture?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, alternative-proof, prime-gaps

what sort of proof did Tchebycheff use to prove Bertrand's conjecture? did he use proof by contradiction or induction? the reason i'm asking is because I'm looking for Chebyshev's proof that is a bit interesting than just direct proof. also it would be helpful if someone shares a link for a detailed proof for Chebyshev-Bertrand conjecture.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You should for example give this reference https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_of_Bertrand%27s_postulate

Comment: Nearly everyone who gives a proof, gives the version due to Erdos. I found Chebyshev's proof in Harold Shapiro's textbook, Introduction to the Theory of Numbers.

Comment: Also, have a look at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2545913/book-chapters-on-either-ramanujan-or-chebychev-proof-of-bertrand-postulate

Comment: @GerryMyerson thank you very much! that is helpful.